# Trigger to tally my leave days

Tags: sql

Goodday I would like to write a trigger which will return a sum of my leave days . I have written the below trigger but get the error .Ambiguous column name 'leaveEarned'.Ambiguous column name 'leaveTaken'. How can i write this better , thanks

```
    CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tgr_update_Leavesum ON dbo.diary  
     FOR INSERT, UPDATE  
      AS  
      BEGIN --Trigger   
      IF UPDATE(LeaveSum)      
       UPDATE Diary  
        SET LeaveSum =  (select sum(leaveEarned) )- (select sum(leaveTaken) )
           FROM Diary D INNER JOIN inserted ON D.DayId = inserted.DayId  

              END --Trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tgr_update_Leavesum ON dbo.diary  
     FOR INSERT, UPDATE  
      AS  
      BEGIN --Trigger   
      IF UPDATE(LeaveSum)      
       UPDATE Diary  
        SET LeaveSum =  (select sum(inserted.leaveEarned) - sum(inserted.leaveTaken)
           FROM Diary D INNER JOIN inserted ON D.DayId = inserted.DayId ) 

              END --Trigger
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , i have tried the block of code , but now get the following error message.An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.